# Security concern for AWS amplify and Dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I'm implementing my project in reactnative with AWS amplify. I need to make a separate expressjs app for api.

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
AWS.config.update({ region: AWSregion }); //AWSregion is a variable
```

This two lines and the Table name is enough to get into Dynamodb database from the localhost using expressjs. I wonder it requires no security credentials like accesskey and secret key.
My concern is if anybody can get my table name and know my zone, they can also access in the same way.
Is there a way to prevent that or make it more secure?

Thanks.

Comment: From your local machine? If you've previously ran `aws configure`, its using those credentials.

Comment: Ohh! I forgot. I had done that. Thanks.